# How to use parameterized query for LIKE operator in Hibernate HQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hibernate, hql

I occured a Hibernate Query problem when I's attempting to query data by LIKE operator with parameterized value, the following is my code fragment for doing it:

```
String hql = "FROM Customer WHERE username LIKE :username";
Query query =sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("username", "%" + keyword + "%")
```

The above code runs alwasy with exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: LIKE near line 1
```

It's ok for using other query operators like =, !=, > with parameterized values, and just get confused to this and how can I use Hibernate query's like operator with parameterized values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FROM Customer WHERE username LIKE ':username'.. Looks like you missed single quotes!!

Comment: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?483929-Using-Parameters-in-MySQL-LIKE-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String hql = "FROM Customer WHERE username LIKE ':username'";
Query query =sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("username", "%" + keyword + "%")
```